# Failed regex: for Rubular is ok

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this piece of string and I must remove the exact match (the span tag):

```
to_clean= "<p><span style=\"font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;\">Tratto da una storia vera e interpretato da&nbsp;<strong>Tom Cruise</strong> nel ruolo del colonnello Claus von Stauffenberg,&nbsp;<strong>Operazione Valchiria</strong>&nbsp;&egrave; la cronaca del coraggioso e ingegnoso piano per eliminare uno dei pi&ugrave; perversi tiranni che il mondo abbia mai conosciuto. Orgoglioso della divisa che indossa, il colonnello Stauffenberg &egrave; un ufficiale leale che ama il suo paese, ma che &egrave; stato costretto ad assistere con orrore all'ascesa di Hitler e alla Seconda Guerra Mondiale. Ha continuato a servire nell'esercito, sempre con la speranza che qualcuno trovasse il modo per fermare Hitler prima che l'Europa e la Germania fossero distrutte. Quando si rende conto che il tempo stringe, Stauffenberg decide di entrare in azione e nel 1942 cerca di persuadere i comandanti del fronte orientale a rovesciare Hitler. Poi, nel 1943, mentre si sta riprendendo dalle ferite subite in combattimento, si unisce a un gruppo di uomini inseriti nei ranghi del potere che cospirano contro il tiranno. La loro strategia prevede di usare lo stesso piano di emergenza di Hitler per consolidare il paese nell'eventualit&agrave; della sua morte - l'Operazione Valchiria - per assassinare il dittatore e rovesciare il governo nazista. Con il futuro del mondo e il destino di milioni di persone, oltre alla vita della moglie e dei figli, appesi a un filo, Stauffenberg da oppositore di Hitler diventa l'uomo che deve uccidere Hitler.<br />\r\nIl film, diretto dal regista&nbsp;<strong>Bryan Singer</strong>&nbsp;(<em>I soliti sospetti, X-Men, Superman Returns</em>) vede nel cast, oltre a Cruise, anche Kenneth Branagh, Bill Nighy, Tom Wilkinson, Carice van Houten, Thomas Kretschmann, Eddie Izzard, Christian Berkel e Terence Stamp.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nIl DVD, della durata di&nbsp;<strong>116 minuti</strong>, viene presentato con video 16:9 in formato anamorfico 1.85:1 e tracce audio italiano e inglese Dolby Digital 5.1 e <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">i</span><strong>taliano DTS 5.1</strong>. Tra i contenuti speciali troviamo <em>La storia del film, Prendere il volo</em>, due backstage sui luoghi del set, uno in Africa e uno a Berlino, una galleria fotografica e il trailer originale. Verr&agrave; commercializzato a partire dal&nbsp;<strong>16 settembre</strong>, assieme alla versione in alta definizione su Blu-ray Disc.</span></p>"
```

My ruby line to remove the span is this:

```
to_clean.gsub!( /<span style="font-size: 10pt; color: rgb\(85, 85, 85\); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;">(.*?)<\/span>/s, '\1')
```

I try also with

```
to_clean.gsub!( /<span style=\"font-size: 10pt; color: rgb\(85, 85, 85\); font-family: helvetica; font-weight: normal; line-height: 14pt;\">(.*?)<\/span>/s, '\1')
```

On Rubular everything is ok, but my gsub! return nil.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the span"? What is `to_clean`? `gsub!` return[s] `nil`; so what? Any idea about what?

Comment: @sawa edited. to_clean of course is the string.

Comment: You need to use `m` modifier for multiline, since there are `\r\n` in the string: `to_clean.gsub!( /…/m, …)`

Comment: The match doesn't work. I think the problem are the double quotes but I cannot find a way to solve it.

Comment: Is the input *always* precisely similar to what you're showing?

Comment: I'm trying with "m" modifier...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `m` modifier for multiline regexp, since there are `\r\n` in the string:

```
#                  ⇓
to_clean.gsub!( /…/m, …)
#                  ⇑
```

This will work.